# Get byte from number problem

Tags: javascript

I have test array of hex(radix 16) numbers

```
var numbers = ["01","02","a1"];
```

and I convert them to int(radix 10) by using

```
var num = parseInt(temp.join(''), 16);
```

where temp is an number in the array of numbers.

I extract byte like

```
( num >> (8*index_byte) & 0xFF)
```

but I dont get value  like "03", problem is that I get just 3. How to get like "01" not 1 or "02" not 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
num = 1;
if (String(num).length < 2)
{
    num = "0" + num;
}
```

Comment: var num = 1; num = num.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + num : num; for simple comparisons you can use ternary (it`s said that it will produce faster code, not very sure, give it a try)

Answer (score 1):

`03` **is** `3` by all means.

Your only option is padding the number yourself:

```
var byte = "0" + (num >> (8 * index_byte) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.js` from [jsxt](http://code.google.com/p/jsxt/source/browse/trunk/js/String.js).

```
var fnumber = '%02d'.sprintf( num>>(8*index_byte) & 0xFF );
```